# Where do I change the date in this countdown function?

Tags: javascript, function, countdown

I just downloaded this countdown script (JavaScript) but I can't figure out how to change the date that the timer will countdown to. 
Original Script:

```
$(function(){
var now = new Date();
// comment out the line below and change the date of your countdown here
var in30Days = new Date( now.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );
// year to countdown to
var countdownYear = in30Days.getFullYear();
// month to countdown to 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb, etc
var countdownMonth = in30Days.getMonth();
// day to countdown to
var countdownDay = in30Days.getDate();

var countdownDate = new Date( countdownYear, countdownMonth, countdownDay );

setupCountdownTimer( countdownDate );

spaceParallax();

hideIphoneBar();

$("[placeholder]").togglePlaceholder();

setupSignupForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe countdownDate...
By default it is built with now + 30 days? You may change this.

Important part is :

```
setupCountdownTimer( countdownDate );

spaceParallax();

hideIphoneBar();

$("[placeholder]").togglePlaceholder();

setupSignupForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself telling how to do it:

```
// comment out the line below and change the date of your countdown here
var in30Days = new Date( now.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) );
// year to countdown to
var countdownYear = in30Days.getFullYear();
// month to countdown to 0 = Jan, 1 = Feb, etc
var countdownMonth = in30Days.getMonth();
// day to countdown to
var countdownDay = in30Days.getDate();
```

Following line creates the countDownDate, pass the year,month and day to the function

```
var countdownDate = new Date( countdownYear, countdownMonth, countdownDay );

setupCountdownTimer( countdownDate );
```